# About product beetween the Matrix and a Vector

Tags: matrices

Good evening everyone. Could someone please answer to the following question : 
Is the product between a special orthogonal matrix and a vector commutative?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is a “special orthogonal matrix”?

Comment: Good evening Mr Santos. A special orthogonal matrix Is a Matrix that its determinante value is +1. Regarding my question I want to know if the production beetween a special orthogonal matrix and a compatibile Vector is commutative. For example let A be a special orthogonal matrix of dimension 3 × 3 and let V be a vector of dimension 3 × 1 this equality is possible: A×V=V×A

Comment: And what does $V\times A$ mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you multiply the matrices by vectors you have to be aware of the dimensions to follow a particular pattern.

In general When you want to multiply matrices the middle dimension should match.

That is you can only multiply a $m\times n$ matrix by a $n\times k$ matrix.

A Vector is either a column vector in which case it is considered an $m\times 1$ matrix or a row vector which is considered as a  $1\times n$ matrix.

So it is possible to multiply a $1\times  m$ matrix ( which is a row vector ) by a $m\times n$ matrix or a $m\times n $ matrix by a $n\times 1$ matrix (which is a column vector)

Comment: Good evening Mr Kermani and thank you for your answer.Your answer is clear but specifically I wanted to know another thing. Let me explain better with an example: let A be a special orthogonal matrix of dimension 3 × 3 and let V be a vector of dimension 3 × 1. So I want to know if this equality is possible: A×V=V×A

Comment: $AV $is possible but $VA$ is not possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Kermani. Another question: when and under what conditions the previous equation is possibile?

Comment: If you consider $V^{T}A$where $V^{T}$ is the transpose of $V$

Comment: Thanks a lot.Your answer is clear and satisfying.

Comment: Thank you for your attention and understanding.